# How to search in Google for inner links with a specific query parameter

Tags: search-engine, affiliate

I'm wondering whether I can search in google for pages that contain links with specific query parameters. For example, I need to find websites that have affiliate links using Tapfilliate (for example site.com?tap=*). So I need to search for links containing "?tap=".

Is there a way I can do that using Google? Or if you can think of some tool that will help me find such websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed you can. That is called (or at least when I learned it in University), `Google Hacking`. Take a look at [this](http://www.mrjoeyjohnson.com/Google.Hacking.Filters.pdf) which will give you a small insight on the basic operators you can use.

Google hacking involves things like "searching for certaint words in a title", or in the full page, searching in websites like "pastebin", etc etc etc. It all depends on your creativity to know what to look for.

Comment: That's a really helpful document. There are many things I didn't know. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Glad it helped! If it was a useful answer, also upvote it! And keep it going with the Google hacking. Might be difficult at first but once you get the hang of it, it is easier and more useful as you know WHAT to search! @AleksandarGinovski